# How to sum numbers by a specific word separated by semi colon in bash

Tags: bash, awk

To be more specific on the path for instance i have file as below;

file.txt

> ```
> apple;10;
> tomato;5;
> apple;5;
> banana;10;
> banana;5;
> tomato;10;
> banana;10;
> apple;5;
> ```

I want to sum numbers by item using bash as a result ;

file.output

> ```
> apple;20;
> banana;25;
> tomato;15;
> ```

Another word is i need to simplify the file. How can achieve this kind of output as a separate file in bash ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: i've tried with php so far, however, it counts one by one so written in the db table.

Comment: I mean what did you try to solve it with `bash`?

Comment: should it be in sorted order?

Comment: it depends which could use less cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following awk, if you need output in same sequence as Input_file then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F";" '!a[$1]{b[++i]=$1} {a[$1]+=$2;} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print b[j] FS a[b[j]] FS}}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
apple;20;
tomato;15;
banana;25;
```

If you don't bother about sequence as per your Input_file then you could simply try following:

```
awk -F";" '{a[$1]+=$2;} END{for(i in a){print i FS a[i] FS}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: thats works like a charm . Thank you.